# Using std::less to Create an std::map Winding Around the Origin

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, cartesian-coordinates

## Introduction

Hello! I'm writing a simulation that operates in a non-trivial space. This system occupies an undetermined amount of space around a centered origin. Right now, I'm implementing an xy point class 'Pos' to join my coordinates and to act as a key for my containers (containing finite blocks of data). I'd like the data around the origin to be spatially coherent in memory.

My goal for this question is to write a specialization for std::less that, if (integral) positions were inserted into the map, they would be ordered according to a counter clockwise winding order.

I imagine that cells :

4 3 2
5 0 1
6 7 8 9

would become

0, 1, 2, 3, ... .

## Question

How should I wrap my mind around writing an std::less, so that I can *wrap my points around*, like this? How can I understand how the solution follows [**strict weak ordering**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) and avoids other pitfalls?
Finally, how would you best approach or write this function with the tools available in C++11?

(If using an unordered map and iterating linearly through a bounding box surrounding a dynamic origin is a much more flexible and efficient solution for my purposes, feel free to write an implementation for it, but I won't be marking it as the best answer.)

---

## Aside

I've been learning by implementing naive attempts, but I believe it would be better for myself to solve this with a discussion and sound explanation than luck.

Here's a snap of context.

```
struct Pos
{
    short x;
    short y;
    Pos(short x, short y);
    Pos(const Pos& p);
    void operator=(const Pos& p);
    ~Pos() = default;
};
namespace std {
    template<> struct less<Pos> {
        bool operator()(const Pos& p1, const Pos& p2) const {
            //Implementation
        }
    }
}
```

*This is my first question, and I've tried to follow the rules. If I've done anything wrong, please be supportive and I'll do my best to put things in order. Thanks for your support!*

Comment: You need a function that takes an X,Y pair and converts it to an ordinal representing it's position around the spiral. It's OK if your sequence has gaps but it can't have overlaps. So I'd start by finding the "ring" that your point is in (the larger of abs(x-center) and abs(y-center)) and start with your base value being the area of every ring inside of that (something like (ring-1)^2) then add the ordinal of how far you are along the current ring (find which edge you are on and how far along it you are). When your points are sorted by this ordinal then they will be in spiral order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete and working solution using C++11 features.

I define `radius()` and `angle()` member functions for `Point`. The "radius" is using the [**maximum norm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_norm) `max(abs(x), abs(y))` to give square rings equal distance to the origin. For the polar angle I use the convention of angles in `[0, 2 pi]`. The Standard Library math function `atan2` gives results in the `[-pi, +pi]` range, so I add `2 pi` for negative results.

Instead of specializing `std::less` inside `namespace std`, it's easier to define your own `operator<` for `Point` because this will automatically work with `std::less`.

To implement the comparison, I use another C++11 facility, namely `forward_as_tuple` which takes a `Point` struct and converts this into a `std::tuple<int, int>`. Because `std::tuple` already has an `operator<` that does the right thing (lexicographic comparison on its members in order that you supplied), the comparison between `Point` is now done using radius first and angles second.

Code follows below (and which prints the points in the correct order).

```
#include <cmath>        // abs, atan, atan2, max
#include <iostream>     // cout
#include <map>          // map
#include <tuple>        // forward_as_tuple

struct Point
{
    int x, y;    

    int radius() const
    {
        // block-wise radius, use Pythagoras for ring-wise radius
        return std::max(std::abs(x), std::abs(y));
    }

    double angle() const
    {
        // result of atan2 in [-pi, +pi]
        auto a = std::atan2(y, x);

        // we want result in [0, 2 pi]
        if (a < 0)             
            a += 8 * std::atan(1); // add 2 pi
        return a;
    }

    friend bool operator<(Point const& L, Point const& R)
    {
        // delegate to operator< of std::tuple
        return 
            std::forward_as_tuple(L.radius(), L.angle()) < 
            std::forward_as_tuple(R.radius(), R.angle())
        ;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point const& p)
    {
        return os << "{" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "}"; 
    }
};

int main() 
{    
    auto point_map = std::map<Point, int> { 
        {{-1, 1}, 4}, {{ 0, 1}, 3}, {{ 1, 1}, 2}, 
        {{-1, 0}, 5}, {{ 0, 0}, 0}, {{ 1, 0}, 1},
        {{-1,-1}, 6}, {{ 0,-1}, 7}, {{ 1,-1}, 8}
    };

    for (auto&& elem : point_map)
        std::cout << elem.second << ",";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd637b89d527c505) that prints

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,

**NOTE:** In case you extend this to the third ring, the 9 will not be adjacent to the 8, instead you will get a slightly different spiral

```
15 14 13 12 11
16  4  3  2 10
17  5  0  1  9
18  6  7  8 24
19 20 21 22 23
```

The reason is that an angle of 0 will be the first element of the new ring. You can tweak this but the code for `angle()` will quickly become very messy (ring-dependent among others). On the other hand, the numbers from the origin out to the right are odd squares this way (1, 9, 25, etc.).

Comment: That's definitely less important than the code simplicity.  

I love your answer. It's a simple, effective answer with a concrete explanation and a working c++11 implementation *that I can compile and run on a browser!* I really appreciate it.

Comment: glad to have been of help!

Comment: Your radius formula is wrong. Should be sqrt(x^2 + y^2).

Comment: @sammy no, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_norm In general there are p-norms defined as `norm_p(x) = (sum_i (x_i^p))^(1/p)`. For p=2 you get the traditional radius that you mention (Pythagoras rule), for p=1 the Manhattan "taxicab" norm and for p=inifinity you get a square ring as radius. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: The norm is not enough to offer strict ordering for all the elements in the R^2 space

Comment: @sammy can you give an example where the axioms of a norm are violated? I define `<` in terms of the norm *and the angle* to distinguish types with the same "radius"

Comment: (5, 0) will be ordered before (4, 4), because norm1=5, norm2=4. But r1=5, r2=5.6. You offer an ordering, but it's not the required one.

Comment: @sammy from the OP's formulation of his question, I interpreted it as a square spiral, not a circular one, and the OP didn't indicate otherwise.  Given that, `(4, 4) < (0, 5)` using my maximum norm. If you want a circular spiral, indeed use the convential radius, those points will flip their ordering, but the rest of the code remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try to solve this equivalent problem : Write a function `f : (Z, Z) -> Z`, where `N` is the set of integers, such that if you started writing numbers from `0` starting at the origin, and going in a counter-clockwise outward spiral, the number at `(x,y)` would be `f(x,y)`.

We will using the following observations :

1. The last element of the `k`-th rung of the spiral, `(k, -k)` satisfies `f(k, -k) = (2k+1)^2 - 1`.
2. Every "arm" of the `k`-th rung(for k>0) has `k+1` elements.
3. `(x,y)` lies on the `max(|x|, |y|)`-th rung.

Using the above, you can come up with a piece-wise description for `f` based on which co-ordinate defines the rung. Thus, you have a constant time method to compute `f`. Functionally, you can define `less( (x1,y1), (x2,y2) ) = less(f(x1,y1), f(x2,y2))`.

Answer (score 0):

An often used solution is to convert to polar coordinates.

You can define a less operator to order first by distance to center then by angle.

Comment: I like it! My first thoughts involved a distance squared and then by quadrant - but I ran into collisions at reflections inside the quadrants.